# Android build tools unaligned 2.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, build-tools

I have found that when trying to create a signed release build, the apk does not get aligned. Anyone else find this? Is there anything you needed change to get this to work?

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0
```

gradle command:

```
assembleRelease
```

Temp solution: Temporarily I set build tools back to 2.1.3 and it works fine.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle.`